# Can I completely disable a PCI-slot in Linux?

Tags: linux-kernel, pci, video-card

Like many of you, I like to play a game every once in a while. Since I use Linux for my daily tasks (programming, writing papers, browsing, etc.), I solely exploit my graphics-card capabilities in Windows while gaming.

Lately I noticed my energy-bills got really high and I would like to reduce the energy consumption of my computer. My graphics-card uses 110 watt idle, whereas a low-end Radeon HD5xxx only uses 5 watt. I *think* my computer is powered on 40 hours a week, whereof only 3 hours of gaming. This means I waste 202 kWh a year (!).

I figured I could just buy a DVI splitter and a low-end Radeon-card, and disable the PCI-slot of the high-end card in Linux. I Googled a bit, but I'm not sure which search-terms to use, so I haven't found anything useful.

**Too long, didn't read**: Is it possible to cut of the power of a PCI-slot using Linux?

Comment: I'm not sure what your prevailing electricity prices are, but around here 202kWh would cost you about $30.

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/questions/4546/how-do-i-turn-off-pci-devices

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.

What your asking isn't even a "Linux" question, but a motherboard question - is it *electrically* possible to do this.

The answer is still no.

The only chance you would have, would be to get the spec of the chip/card which is *in* the slot, and see if there is a bit you can set on it which would "disable" it, or put it into some "low power mode".

Comment: Ok, thanks for your answer and I'm sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: There are SOME cases I've seen where you can do this. Google PCI hotplug commands. *IF* your card supports hot-plug, and *IF* your driver does, and *IF* the slot on your motherboard has power control going to it so that it can PHYSICALLY power-down the slot - you can do this. Most slots do NOT support this. Check the "slot capability" and "slot control" registers..